# Transactions qty unreservation process with an undesired behaviour

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

In AX 2012 R2 we face an issue with the unreservation process of any sales order line or transfer order line.

The standard reservation process will update the transaction and the origin's order line quantities with the quantity of the available batch that has been picked.

Our issue occurs with the unreservation, because AX will maintain the quantity of the picked batch, not the original from the order line.

How can we fix/customize this behavior?